# Need to convert scientific value to text

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, epplus

I am trying to convert csv to xls in which there is Bank Account No (16 digit) need to convert it to text

I tried with EPPlus package by which xls is getting generated easily but Bank Account column gets  converted to scientific value.Also tried to convert column to numeric and text but thats not working

```
    private void csvToXls(string source,string destination,string fileName)
    {
        string csvFileName = source;
        string excelFileName = destination+"/"+fileName+".xls";

        string worksheetsName = "sheet 1";

        bool firstRowIsHeader = false;

        var format = new ExcelTextFormat();
        format.Delimiter = '|';
        format.EOL = "\n";              // DEFAULT IS "\r\n";
                                        // format.TextQualifier = '"';

        using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(excelFileName)))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheetsName);
            worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromText(new FileInfo(csvFileName), format, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.None, firstRowIsHeader);

            foreach (var cell in worksheet.Cells["C:C"])
            {
                cell.Value = Convert.ToString(cell.Value);

            }

            foreach (var cell in worksheet.Cells["AC:AC"])
            {
                cell.Value = Convert.ToString(cell.Value); 
            }
            worksheet.Cells["C:C"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#0";
            worksheet.Cells["C:C"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";
            worksheet.Cells["AC:AC"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";


            package.Save();
        }
    }
```

Need to convert columns to text which should not be scientific value.Please suggest

Input : In test.csv below input is there

IMDATA||12345678910124567895274|1|NAME|||||||||TEST|||||||||||TESTING||||3301003726558|TDATASTING|TESTING|27-09-2019

Getting Output : 
[image: Wrong Output]

Expected Output : 
[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Showing an example input, what you are getting & what you are hoping to get may help us.

Comment: @PaulF added the Input data **12345678910124567895274** value is getting as scientific value in xls

Comment: Why not just import into Excel using an Excel tool?  You can use the `Legacy Wizard`, `Power Query`, or `VBA` and just set that column format to Text Before saving it to the worksheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide `eDataTypes` to `LoadFromText` method for each column, if no types provide for the column it will set to the `General` by default

So, provide the `eDataTypes to ExcelTextFormat.

I just added for 3 columns and its worked well.

```
public static void csvToXls(string source, string destination, string fileName)
{
    string csvFileName = source;
    string excelFileName = destination + "/" + fileName + ".xls";

    string worksheetsName = "sheet 1";
    bool firstRowIsHeader = false;

    var format = new ExcelTextFormat();
    var edataTypes = new eDataTypes[] { eDataTypes.String, eDataTypes.String, eDataTypes.String };
    format.DataTypes = edataTypes;
    format.Delimiter = '|';
    format.EOL = "\n";              // DEFAULT IS "\r\n";
                                    // format.TextQualifier = '"';
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(excelFileName)))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheetsName);
        worksheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromText(new FileInfo(csvFileName), format, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.None, firstRowIsHeader);

        package.Save();
    }
}
```

**OR**

You can try to read the text manually

```
public static  void csvToXls(string source, string destination, string fileName)
{
    string csvFileName = source;
    string excelFileName = destination + "/" + fileName + ".xls";

    string worksheetsName = "sheet 1";

    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(new FileInfo(excelFileName)))
    {
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(worksheetsName);

        var text = File.ReadAllText(source);
        var rows = text.Split('\n');

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rows.Length; rowIndex++)
        {
            var excelRow = worksheet.Row(rowIndex+1);

            var columns = rows[rowIndex].Split('|');

            for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < columns.Length; colIndex++)
            {
                worksheet.Cells[rowIndex +1, colIndex +1].Value = columns[colIndex];
            }
        }

        package.Save();
    }
}
```

Comment: is there any way to convert xls to csv or xlsx to csv Please suggest ?

Comment: @daoootim yes there are many ways. You can use `EP PLUS` to generate the excel file and CSV is a normal text file which can be easily generated by .net existing library `System.IO.File.WriteAllText`.